# Let $1<p$, $q<\infty$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Show that $(B^n_p)^* = B^n_q$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I am stuck on this question: Let $1<p$, $q<\infty$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Show that $(B^n_p)^* = B^n_q$. Should I apply the Hölder inequality here?

Comment: Sorry, just edited.

Comment: What is $B^{n}$?

Comment: Closed unit ball. For example $B^n_2 = \{x\in R^n : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

This will follow by Hahn-Banach Theorem
\begin{align*}
\|x\|_{X}=\max\{\left|\left<x,x^{\ast}\right>\right|: \|x^{\ast}\|_{X^{\ast}}\leq 1\},
\end{align*}
and the Riesz Representation Theorem that $(L^{p})^{\ast}=L^{q}$ for conjugate $1<p,q<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! But I have not learned these two theorems before. Is there another way I can prove it?

Comment: You must know the fact that $(L^{p})^{\ast}=L^{q}$, I think.

Comment: I see. Thanks for helping!